# RxJava rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException with filter and map

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I just started playing around with RxJava/RxAndroid and have some problems to understand how to correctly handle backpressure.

I have a file scanner observable that scans directories and emits files. These files should be processed as fast as possible and without skipping any of them.

So the pipeline looks like this:
`Observable<File> -> Filter<File, Boolean> {check if file is of type .xyz}`

Unfortunately, I get the **rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException** error. So I read about backpressure and if I understand it right, loss less options are only buffers and windows.

I tried `onBackpressureBuffer(), buffer() and window()`. While all the `onBackpressureX()` commands seem to have no effects, buffer() groups items into a `List<File>`. My questions are:

1. How am I supposed to filter these groups? `filter(<List<File>>, Boolean)` would make no sense...
2. How can I implement in my filescanner observable backpressure handling so that it waits until my pipeline / operators / subscribers have capacity?
3. Is it good practice to transform items with e.g. `map()` into XYZ-Entities and store them in a separate List without being active subscriber but as side-effect in the operator?

Some feedback or even hints would help a lot and be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `onBackPressureDrop()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The onBackPressureX() commands did not work because of the order(?) - see my answer. Moreover, one requirement was for the operation to be lossless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the solution to the problem:
This code was not working:

```
Observable<File> task = scanner.getProcessDirectoryTask(mountPoint);
Subscription _subscription = task
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .onBackpressureBuffer(10000)
        .filter(new Func1<File, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(File file) {
                return file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("xyz");
            }
        })
        .buffer(100)
        .subscribe(new Observer<List<File>>() { /*whatever you want to do*/ }
```

However this code **is** working:

```
Observable<File> task = scanner.getProcessDirectoryTask(mountPoint);
Subscription _subscription = task
        .onBackpressureBuffer(10000)
        .filter(new Func1<File, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call(File file) {
                return file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("xyz");
            }
        })
        .buffer(100)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<List<File>>() { /*whatever you want to do*/ }
```

So it seems the order with `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` make a huge difference!

My third question is kind of off-topic but still open. Maybe someone can comment on this.

Comment: Yes, Schedulers.io() create another Thread to process your request to files in a Thread different from the MainThread, so you can't  interact to views in subcription. AndroidSchedulers.mainThread create a subscriber to be executed in MainThread.

Comment: You have to put `onBackpressureXXX` before the sensitive operation such as `observeOn`. But how is `getProcessDirectoryTask` implemented? Standard sources should support backpressure.

Comment: It's created using Observable.create() and with the long running file-scan operation in the OnSubscribe.